# Update value of a template tag from views in django

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a form in Django to provide information regarding various tasks on a particular day, and these tasks are saved as model objects. I render the tasks on the HTML page as shown as follows in a grid view.
[(Click Here for the Grid View)](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/samples/03_extensions/27_grid_view.html)
 But now I want to be able to show the tasks only on that particular day. Using the arrows on the top right corner, I want to be able to filter the tasks and display them.

I have already extracted the current date from the javascript of the calendar and send it via ajax call in my views.py. From there I filter the tasks according to the date, but when once I change the view (ie., the date from the left and right corner arrows) I am able to capture the updated date but not able to update the template tags on the JS side.

views.py

```py
# The default view when the page loads for the first time
# As it loads by default to the current date, so filtering tasks on the current date.
def schedule(request):

    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    tasks = Tasks.objects.filter(schedule_date=today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

    context = {
        "tasks": processes,
    }

    return render(request, r'dhtmlx_grid_view.html',context)
.
.
.
.
#Calling this function when there is a view change (ie., when you navigate to a new date)
@csrf_exempt
def load_tasks(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        view_date = request.POST.get('new_date')
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(view_date, '%b %d %Y')

        tasks= Tasks.objects.filter(schedule_date= date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

        context = {
            'tasks': task
        }
        return render(request, r'dhtmlx_grid_view.html',context)
```

dhtmlx_grid_view.html (In the JS section of the HTML file)

```js
{# Using ajax post call to send the changed date #}
scheduler.attachEvent("onViewChange", function (new_mode, new_date) {

            $.ajax({
                url: {% url 'tasks:load-tasks' %},
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    'new_date': String(new_date).substring(4,15),
                    'new_mode': new_mode,

                },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("Successful")
                }
            });
        })
.
.
.
.

{# Using the template tags as follows to render the variable #}
        var tasks = [

            {% for i in tasks %}
                {
                    key: "{{ i.grouper }}", label: "{{ i.grouper }}", open: true, children: [
                            {% for j in i.list %}
                                {key: {{ j.sub_process_id }}, label: "{{ j.sub_process }}"},
                                {% endfor %}
                    ]
                },
            {% endfor %}
        ];
```

How do I change the value of `tasks` on the template side from `load-tasks` method?

Is there a way to do this, as even though I store the changed date and filter, I am not able to update the values of the `<QuerySet>` ie., `tasks` on the template side.

Let me know if you need any additional information

Answer (score 1):

The tags that are loaded in the template are only evaluated when the HTML file is originally generated. Those tags will not work again for future AJAX requests. You need to change the DOM in the callback from the `ajax` call.

```
scheduler.attachEvent("onViewChange", function (new_mode, new_date) {

            $.ajax({
                url: {% url 'tasks:load-tasks' %},
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    'new_date': String(new_date).substring(4,15),
                    'new_mode': new_mode,

                },
                success: function (result) {
                    // Set the new DOM up in here
                }
            });
        })
```

Comment: In the success function, how do I update existing the value of the template tag {{ tasks }} ??

Comment: You need to do this using JavaScript, since that's the programming languages that runs in the browser. For example, you can write something like `document.getElementById('tasksElement').innerHTML = result;` (not exactly this, but you get the point hopefully).

Comment: Yes I understand, but in my case {{ tasks }} is a <QuerySet> with model objects and using a Django template for loop I render them on dhtmlx grid view, there is no such specific Html component I have given to it. If not this way, can I do the filtering on the javascript side? by {{ Tasks.filter(date==variable) }} and render this object, if I do this, how do I pass a variable inside  the template tag {{ '''''  }} ?